# Media Queries don't work in SharePoint Online 2019 (SPOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, media-queries

Our company migrated to SharePoint Online 2019 SPOC. I use Media Queries in my React/Typescript app which has been running on SharePoint. After the migration media queries stopped working.
Please, do you know what to do to make them working again?

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1800px) {
  #gridContainer {
    height: 200px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 1800px) and (max-device-width: 2000px) {
  #gridContainer {
    height: 500px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 2000px) {
  #gridContainer {
    height: 800px !important;
  }
}
```